# Use Form to create new page

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to find a way for a user to come to my site and fill in a form and when they submit the form a new webpage is made. I want to make it create a new webpage in an admin area so I can view what they have submitted without having to troll my databases. I am assuming this is possible because the concept is hardly new, but hours of scanning google has left me empty handed on any remotely close tutorial or anything of that nature. Perhaps I simply do not know how to word it, I am very new at forms but I am assuming this has something to do with the form action. Are there tutorials for this that someone can link me to or can someone give me a quick explanation? I can figure out the work for myself, I just need a point in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: You're going to need to learn about 1) persistant storage (a database), 2) a server side programming language (HTML is purely for creating the structure of a web page), and ... I dunno, a lot more.  I would suggest you actually look at a CMS (content management system) and see if that gets you where you want to go.

Comment: Thanks, I've worked with php a bit in the past and I sort of know how to get html and php to communicate and store information on the database. I'm guessing from your response there is no work around for the php bit, I was hoping just for the form data to be put in a simple html document where I could just log in and read it all, but I guess it would be more complicated than that. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Databases don't interact with HTML in that way without some sort of application sitting between the site and the database.  It doesn't have to be a PHP application, but something is going to have to store and get data from the db, and something is going to have to dynamically create these pages you want.  And that's going to be some sort of programming language  -- or a content management system  like Drupal.

Comment: Okay thanks, if you can just copy paste that in to an answer I'll accept it. Thank you for the clear explanation, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to learn about 1) persistant storage (a database), 2) a server side programming language (HTML is purely for creating the structure of a web page), and ... I dunno, a lot more. I would suggest you actually look at a CMS (content management system) and see if that gets you where you want to go.

Databases don't interact with HTML in that way without some sort of application sitting between the site and the database. It doesn't have to be a PHP application, but something is going to have to store and get data from the db, and something is going to have to dynamically create these pages you want. And that's going to be some sort of programming language -- or a content management system like Drupal.

(Also, don't forget about security, support, etc.  You write the app, you have to support it.  =)

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but I do hope it helps.  It does sound like there might be a fully implemented solution for you out there already.